# Error while exporting file using ExcelJS - ERROR Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: u.readFile is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, export-to-excel, exceljs

I am trying to export a file on the client side using ExcelJS in Angular 10.

While clicking the export button i get the following error in browser console.

```
core.js:4197 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: u.readFile is not a function
TypeError: u.readFile is not a function
    at exceljs.min.js:3
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone-evergreen.js:960)
    at T (exceljs.min.js:3)
    at exceljs.min.js:3
    at f (exceljs.min.js:17)
    at Generator._invoke (exceljs.min.js:17)
    at Generator.next (exceljs.min.js:17)
    at i (exceljs.min.js:3)
    at s (exceljs.min.js:3)
    at exceljs.min.js:3
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:798)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:750)
    at zone-evergreen.js:860
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:27419)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:569)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:484)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:1621)
```

**app.component.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->

  <!-- serial must : first jquery then popper then bootstrap -->
  <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->


</head>

<body>

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-2">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" (click)='exportAsExcelFile()'>Download as Excel</button>
      </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as Excel from 'exceljs';
import * as fs from 'file-saver';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'resttest10';
    
      async exportAsExcelFile(): Promise<void> {
        // Create workbook and worksheet
        const workbook = new EXCEL.Workbook();
        const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Export_Data');
        const logo = workbook.addImage({
          filename: '/path/to/image',
          extension: 'gif',
        });
        worksheet.addImage(logo, 'A1:B3');
        worksheet.mergeCells('A1:B3');
        // Blank Row
        worksheet.addRow([]);
       // Data
        worksheet.addRow({ id: 1, name: 'John Doe', dob: new Date(1970, 1, 1) });
        worksheet.addRow({ id: 2, name: 'Jane Doe', dob: new Date(1965, 1, 7) });
    
        // Generate Excel File with given name
        console.log('writing to file');
        await workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer().then((data: any) => {
          console.log('buffer');
          const blob = new Blob([data], {
            type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
          });
          console.log('Saving File');
          fs.saveAs(blob, 'Export_Data' + new Date().getHours() + ':'
            + new Date().getMinutes() + ':' + new Date().getSeconds() + '.xlxs');
        });
      }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the image as a base64 encoded string? `const myBase64Image = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG...";` and `workbook.addImage({ base64: myBase64Image,  extension: 'png'});`.

Comment: i have tried removing the whole image section, but still the same error. So i added the console log to see how far it goes. `writing to file` is the last log before it error outs.

Comment: What happens if you add `await` before `workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer()`? So: `await workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer().then(...)`

Comment: Have tried that as well, still the same error.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?